# java.lang.ClassCastException: __redirected.__XMLInputFactory cannot be cast to org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I am migration Java Web Application from jboss 6.0 to wildfly 11. I am getting

> "java.lang.ClassCastException: __redirected.__XMLInputFactory cannot
>   be cast to org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2" while running the code
>   on wildfly 11.0.0.Final. Junit tests are working without error.

Looks like there is some dependency issue in wildfly but unable to find any solution. Appreciate any help to resolve this issue..
I have included following woodstox dependencies in pom.

woodstox-core-asl 4.4.1
stax2-api 3.1.4

Thanks
Sanjay

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by duplicate classes in the classpath.

Wildfly ships stax2-api as part of the woodstocks module, see modules/system/layers/base/org/codehaus/woodstox/main/ in the wildfly dist folder.

If you also have it in your application's lib folder, this will cause issues.

The solution is to either set the dependency to `<scope>provided</scope>` (or build) in pom.xml, or if you really need a special version, exclude wildfly's module via jboss-deployment-structure.xml.

See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly for more information on classloading in Wildfly.